# To close or not to close

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have posted a few questions on StackOverflow.com

They weren't asnswered even though I let them simmer for a while.

I found the answer because - hey.. I'm a real programmer.

Now, my question is ..

```
Do I post my own answer and _vote to close_?
or 
Do I post my answer and _accept my own_ answer_?
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/etiquette-for-closing-your-own-questions

Comment: Its actually the oldest question on this site.

Comment: Oops, second oldest now...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Post your answer and accept it as your answer because that was originally what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Post your answer and accept it.  It may feel like repwhoring, but the goal is to help the *next* person to come along with a similar problem.  And let's be honest, don't you deserve a little rep for working it out yourself?

Comment: you don't get the +15 rep for having your answer accepted, you only get th +2 for accepting an answer

Comment: +2 doesn't count as a little rep?

Comment: its about showing everyone the answer that was needed by the person who posted the question. Rep is for fun.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if we should also add an ability to mark our questions as "I don't need the answer anymore"? Such questions could stop being pushed to the top by the Community User, and should stop showing up in "Unanswered questions".

This touches a bit on all the unanswered questions that are unanswered because the person posting the question never came back to answer it, but that's a different discussion.

Comment: You can close as "no longer relevant" if you want

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that.  I see no reason to close the post.  Unless you are concerned about wasting someone's time.

Comment: I'm concerned that the post would never be Answered.

Answer (score 0):

[Simpsons did it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/etiquette-for-closing-your-own-questions) *(It's a duplicate)*