# Cleaning up questions with Close votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have recently been doing some house keeping on all my questions without accepted answers, and for many, accepting the most suitable answer. I have also voted to close quite a few, as too localised, and now I'm wondering what happens to these? It would be great if mods or others could pull these questions up and also vote if they agree the question is no longer relevant or useful.

Or do I just leave them until eventually they somehow accrue more close votes?

Comment: 10k users (and of course moderators) can see a list of questions with recent close votes. But if you want to ensure that they get closed, you can flag and ask a moderator to step in. They don't always have time to browse this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your close votes [will expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594) if no one else add a vote to the questions, so if you're *sure* they [need closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/etiquette-for-closing-your-own-questions):

- consider flagging them for a moderator, and explaining why the question should be closed.
- post about them here and convince a swarm of meta users to close them for you.
- try waiting, 10k users *might* find them on the close lists and add their close votes to yours.
- as a last resort, consider deleting them - but be aware that there are [restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean) on self-deletion.

Comment: Meta users don't usually take much convincing to cast close votes. ;-)